# How display color message from bash script?

Tags: bash, colors

I found this example:

```
echo -e "This is red->\e[00;31mRED\e[00m"
```

It works if execute direct, from command line, bu if create file like:

```
#! /usr/bin/sh
echo -e "This is red->\e[00;31mRED\e[00m"
```

Doesn't work. How to fix? Or may be possible output in bold?
Please don't use Lua it doesn't installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit** This might be your problem (likely):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "This is red->\e[00;31mRED\e[00m"
```

The reason is that `sh` doesn't have a builtin `echo` command, that supports escapes.

*Alternatively* you might invoke your script like

```
bash ./myscript.sh
```

---

#### Backgrounders

[ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are interpreted by the terminal.

If you run in a pipe/with IO redirected, ouput won't be to a terminal, hence the escapes don't get interpreted.

Hints:

- see [`ansifilter`](http://www.andre-simon.de/zip/download.html#ansifilter) for a tool that can filter ANSI escape sequences (and optionally translate to HTML and others)
- use GNU less, e.g. to get ANSI escapes working in a pager:

  ```
  grep something --colour=always files.* | less -R
  ```

Or simply, as I do

```
# also prevent wrapping long lines
alias less='less -SR'
```

Comment: I cannot use ansifilter - I can use only Bash

Comment: Spotted it! You are _not_ using bash. Edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Use an echo program, not an echo built-in command:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYECHO="`which echo`"
if <test-whether-MYECHO-empty-and-act-accordingly> ...
...
$MYCHO -e "This is red->\e[00;31mRED\e[00m"
```